# Concerning Node.js was Bootstrap npm package recently deprecated?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm-install, deprecated

I am trying to install **Bootstrap** using the `npm install` method. I have been on this for a while now and am wondering if I am doing something wrong? the npm install is still included on [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) site as well as [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap#quick-start) page.

From what I understand using bower has been deprecated. Had serious issues using gulp. Any assistance or a link to an updated tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Following errors occured while trying to install via terminal:

```
~/GitHub/GitSite $ npm install boostrap
npm WARN deprecated boostrap@2.0.0: Package no longer supported.  
Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN gitsite@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ boostrap@2.0.0
updated 1 package in 1.902s
~/GitHub/GitSite $ npm install boostrap jquery popper.js --save
npm WARN deprecated boostrap@2.0.0: Package no longer supported.  
Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN gitsite@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ boostrap@2.0.0
+ jquery@3.3.1
+ popper.js@1.14.3
updated 3 packages in 2.216s
```

In the download was included all the correct folders, however, in node_modules > boostrap there was a README file that said:

---

> Deprecated Package
>
> This package is no longer supported and has been deprecated. To avoid
>   malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name.
>
> Please contact support@npmjs.com if you have questions about this
>   package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ~/GitHub/GitSite $ npm install boostrap

You made a typo buddy, `npm install boostrap` instead of `npm install bootstrap`
Try with the correct package name and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have bootstrap@2.0.0 listed in your package.json dependencies?

try `npm i bootstrap@4.1.0`

Comment: I get a bunch of errors no such file or directory exists. I never saw anything about a package.json file? I watched about 12 tutorials and not one of them was clear about this.

Comment: @Atomica, your package.json file will live in the root directory of your project. If you're unsure about it, you can also run "npm init" which will generate the package.json file for you.

Comment: In case if anyone find this comment helpful : You can try like below as well as per bootstrap documentation $ npm install bootstrap@3 (it will install version bootstrap@3.4.1)