# Fresh Angular-8 project locks to boostrap2

Tags: angular, installation, deprecated

Just started learning Angular.
Angular8 defaults to boostrap@2.0.0 when doing an npm install boostrap. npm doesn't find newer versions doing "npm install boostrap@3" for example.

Where should I look to find the source of the problem? Is this normal?

For starters I googled this problem and only found this (the reason I'm asking in stackoverflow): [Concerning Node.js was Boostrap npm package recently deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013290/concerning-node-js-was-boostrap-npm-package-recently-deprecated)

Now I run "npm ls boostrap" and it only shows boostrap under "my-first-app". Also found boostrap@2.0.0 in packages.json.

Node version: 12.3.1
Angular version: 8.0.0

```
Package      Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@types/node    8.9.5   8.9.5  12.0.7  my-first-app
rxjs           6.4.0   6.4.0   6.5.2  my-first-app
ts-node        7.0.1   7.0.1   8.2.0  my-first-app
tslint        5.15.0  5.15.0  5.17.0  my-first-app
typescript     3.4.5   3.4.5   3.5.1  my-first-app
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to delete the thread, but the obvious problem was the late hours, brain-fog and that I was installing **boostrap** NOT **bootstrap**

[NPMJS website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boostrap)

> This package is no longer supported and has been deprecated. To avoid
>   malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name.

So, the misspelled package has been locked and (gladly?) I'm not the only one installing this dummy module, it has 1,691 weekly installs.

I think the message in the package name should be something along the lines of "please see 'bootstrap' for the css framework" instead of "no longer supported". I understand the message is a generic message for all packages, but it should be a little more obvious that it's an empty package.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Angular widgets library built from the ground up using only Bootstrap 4.

[Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

**Now to answer your question:** 
 - This is an npm related issue it has nothing to do with Angular
 - There is no Bootstrap 3 package in npm.

Available versions for Bootstrap 3 are

```
 - 3.1.1
 - 3.2.0
 - 3.3.0
 - 3.3.2
 - 3.3.4
 - 3.3.5
 - 3.3.6
 - 3.3.7
 - 3.4.0
 - 3.4.1
```

So if you want to install a specific version then use `npm install bootstrap@3.3.7`

for Bootstrap version 4 `npm install bootstrap@4.3.1`

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi, thanks this is really helpful as now I know is related to npm. I saw a tutorial installing boostrap@3 but then that is probably outdated. The thing is how can a default installation have this complicated dependencies problems? I'm really having a hard time finding similar problems with google. I'll look into package.json that for some reason locks to boostrap 2.0.0. Now, installing boostrap@4.3.1 worked with lots of problems and still listing 2.0.0

Comment: Sivuyile TG Magutywa, I think this is solved as I was mispelling the "bootstrap" package and installing the "boostrap" package (missing t) that is a dummy one. Now, in my opinion it should show a message that isn't so generic, and show that it's probably a mispelling (this could be used for lots of packages). Your replies helped me realize this. Can't stress enough, I thank your willingness to help, this mistake was really frustrating